# Axios React - not setting state, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, axios

So here's the code, I simply want to use axios to get, then set that response to the state. Using ES6 arrow functions

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class FieldValues extends Component {
  constructor (props){
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        todos: []
      }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`127.0.0.1:8000/api/todos/`)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({res.data});
      });
  }

  render(){
    console.log(this.state);

  }
}

export default FieldValues;
```

Here's a browser screenshot from my local host serving up json via express and node.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHfH0.png)

And my error - Is it sad to admit that I've been at this for hours now?

Failed to compile.

Error in ./src/App.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected , (15:26)

```
  13 |     axios.get(`127.0.0.1:8000/api/todos/`)
  14 |       .then(res => {
> 15 |         this.setState({res.data});
     |                           ^
  16 |       });
  17 |   }
  18 | 

Error
 @ ./src/index.js 13:11-27
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(res.data)` in the axios success callback to see if you get  data and also are you logging the state in `render()` only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing what you're getting back from your API is an array of ToDos. In that case, you need this:

```
this.setState({todos: res.data});
```

The `setState` call takes in an object. When creating an object, you need to give each property a name and a value. The way you're doing it, you're not giving your property a name. Perhaps you've seen code like this and that's causing confusion:

```
let name = "John";
let obj = {name};
```

The reason THAT works is because in ES6 they added a feature where if your variable name also happens to be the name you want as your property name, you can omit the `{name: name}` duplication. In your case however, A) it's a nested property of `res` so that trick wouldn't work, and B) you want it to be called `todos`.

Comment: Thank you BFree, that removed the error. Yay, but I'm still not logging the json data into the console at all. My array is still empty :/  please help a noob

Comment: Thanks again, I was able to get it to work using your guidance