# Axios React GET request - set state or props from API call?

Tags: reactjs, axios

New to React - I want to make a GET request to my Rails backend via Axios, to bring in what will be static data (just a table with a search function by users) of a list of organizations.

Currently, I got it working the way I would like while passing in an array of organizations I made by hand, as props to my `WholeApp` class. Now, I want to call on the API endpoint to achieve the same effect, but with the real data.

However, when I set state to the list of organizations via the Axios call, I think it tries to render the component before the call is complete, and I get an undefined error in my OrgTable class (which builds the table).

I think I am missing something obvious, but haven't been able to find it. I am pretty sure it is not a syntax error like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42825073/axios-react-not-setting-state-what-am-i-doing-wrong) or that I am not binding correctly without ES6 sytnax.

Here is where I make the Axios call:

```
class WholeApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      filterText: '',
      organizations: []
    };
    this.handleFilterTextInput = this.handleFilterTextInput.bind(this);
  }

  handleFilterTextInput(filterText) {
    this.setState({
      filterText: filterText
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/organizations').then((result) => {
      this.setState({ organizations: result.data });
    });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <TableInfoText />
        <SearchBar
          filterText={this.state.filterText}
          onFilterTextInput={this.handleFilterTextInput}
        />
        <OrgTable
          // orgs={this.props.orgs}
          orgs={this.state.orgs}
          filterText={this.state.filterText}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Also, if I put a debugger inside the return from the `axios.get` call, `this` comes back as undefined. If I use this.props.orgs on the OrgTable, it works correctly (using my hand-made organizations). The uncommented portion using `this.state.orgs` throws the error when it hits the forEach in this:

```
class OrgTable extends Component {
  render () {
    const rows = [];

    this.props.orgs.forEach((org) => {
      if ((org.name + org.city + org.county + org.state + org.zip).toLowerCase().indexOf(this.props.filterText) === -1) {
        return;
      }
      rows.push(<OrgRow org={org} key={org.name}/> );
    });

    return(
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>County</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>ZIP</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

And I am rendering the whole thing from another file, via:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import WholeApp from './App';
import {organizations} from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <WholeApp orgs={organizations} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

**Any ideas how I can get this all wired up correctly?**

Comment: Have you tried mocking your default state with the request to see if it renders without the axios request?

Comment: Yes I was able to get it to render without the request -  but tugce's answer below was the issue... just a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set **organizations** not **org**. Because that's what you update after the ajax request. Change OrgTable properties accordingly.

```
<OrgTable
    orgs={this.state.organizations}
    filterText={this.state.filterText}/>
```

You're also going to want to allow for a placeholder before you have data. Or at least null.

```
{ this.state.organizations && <OrgTable
      orgs={this.state.organizations}
      filterText={this.state.filterText}/> }
```